# Can I input regular expressions at run time

Tags: regex, perl

I wish to input a regular expression from a file or STDIN at run-time

I have tried the code below.

```
$mystr = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
while ($regexp = <STDIN>) {
    chomp $regexp;
    if ($mystr =~ $regexp) {
        print "pattern matched\n";
    } else {
        print "pattern did NOT match\n";
    }
```

Regardless of the regular expression I input there is no match.
I am inputting `m/abc/` for example.

Comment: _Always_ have `use warnings;` and `use strict;` at the beginning

Comment: ( btw, you can generate that string by `my $mystr = join '', 'a'..'z';` )

Comment: Thanks. When I used them I caught a bug and made it work.

Answer (score 3):

The `/`s are only needed to quote an expression as a regex literal. The value of a regex itself never needs to be enclosed in `/`s. So you can simply input `abc` or `a.*z` instead to find a match.

Comment: Thanks. What happens if I want to use a modifier such as m or s? With the delimiters its m/xxx/ and s/xxx/yyy/

Comment: @odbdux, Use `(?s)pat`, `(?m)pat` or `(?sm)pat`; or `(?s:pat)`, `(?m:pat)` or `(?sm:pat)`

Comment: @ikegami I wonder if he meant a leading `m` or `s` (i.e. match/substitute), not the trailing `m` or `s` modifiers?

Comment: Accepting Perl code (as opposed to a regex pattern) from the user is probably quite unwise. If you're right about what they meant, they'd be better off accepting a choice of operation, a pattern, and a replacement string (when appropriate) as separate inputs.

Comment: @ikegami, I agree. So long as I am running the program I can sort of confine the risk to me. The bigger problem is how to avoid code changes during production. The regular expressions I am using are fairly complicated and change frequently so I want to keep them out of the code of possible.

Comment: Re "*The bigger problem is how to avoid code changes during production.*", Then you DEFINITELY don't want to accept Perl code as arguments.